# VB.NET Have whole program loop until user decides to exit?

Tags: vb.net, loops, console

I have a simple program to average ten (user-defined) numbers and then print the result. At the end of the program I'd like to print `Would you like to average a new set of numbers? (Y/N)` If the user inputs `y` than I want the program to execute again from the top. If the user inputs `n` than the program should close. I've tried researching this, but only found ways to have the entire console exit and re-open which is not what I want.

Comment: Can't you just recursively call `Main(args)` if the `ConsoleKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Y` ?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate? I'm just teaching myself VB.NET so I am not entirely familiar with a lot of the techniques.

Comment: I'm a C# guy, so any code I provide will not be familiar, but in a console app there is usually a `static void Main(string[] args)` which is the entry point for the Console app - so when you reach the end of calling whatever you're calling, ask the user for input and if they press the Y key, make a call to the Main method again to start over....

Comment: @SpaceBison - A recursive call could cause issues. First, called enough times, you'd end up with a stack overflow (admittedly, it'd be a LOT of times... but still). Second, if there's any "cleanup" after the "y/n", then that cleanup could occur many, many times as the stack unwinds. I wouldn't recommend recursive function calls to someone new to programming.

Comment: I take your point about beginners and pitfalls, but I have had no issues with using recursive calls in Console apps, but that is because I know how to tightly control it. For me, as a beginner, I'd want to *cause* stack overflows and understand why, then solve it :) - in any case, your solution is a much better fit to the OPs situation though, so +1'd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect what the user has entered you have a couple options:

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

will read the next keystroke. You can then use a simple `Select Case` branch to choose what to do.

You can also use:

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

which will return a string (after the user presses enter). You can then use a simple If statement to determine what's in the string (and repeat the query if something other than "y" or "n" was entered.)

Example:

```
Shared Sub Main()    
    While True
        AverageNums()
        Console.WriteLine( "Do you want to run again? (Y/N)" )
        Dim key = Console.ReadKey()
        If key.Key = ConsoleKey.N Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While    
End Sub

Shared Sub AverageNums()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! This is very educational learning by doing. I wasn't aware, or it didn't occur to me that you could actually have multiple `Sub Main()` statements.

Comment: @Matt - They're called "methods" (`Sub`) or "functions" (`Function`) (the keyword "sub" is based on the older concept of "subroutines") and you can declare as many as you'd like in a Class - the only caveat is that each must have a different name (until you learn about overloading). Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

My response may be a little late in the game, but thought I'd share a compact version implementing a try-catch method.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Do
        Try
            Console.Write("Enter a value: ")
            Console.ReadLine()
            '...

            SomeProcedure()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            Console.Write("Enter another value? (N for No) ")
        End Try

    Loop Until Console.ReadLine() = "N"

End Sub

Sub SomeProcedure()
    '...
End Sub
```